# Update data in new table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have one problem. Two DB's(say DB1 & DB2) are talking to each other.

In DB1 particular row is updated, so I just want to detect the changes from the DB2 and update the new row in DB2.

Please let me know how to di this using JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: I recommend providing some information on what you have already tried to do/researched.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Rest API for update the new rows! Create database triggers in DB1, in the body of triggers write HttpClient for calling the Rest API and update the particular row in DB2.